# Query AD LDS with Powershell and Credentials

Tags: windows, powershell, server, adlds

I can connect to my AD LDS instance using LDP from a Windows server, but I am struggling to connect/bind and query my AD LDS instance with PowerShell from the same server.  I can't figure out the correct PowerShell syntax.

**Here are the connection parameters/steps that work for LDP:**

Server = idm.mydomain.com

Port = 636

Check the SSL checkbox

Once connected to idm.mydomain.com, go to Bind

User = CN=canvas_service,OU=Users,OU=Infrastructure Support,DC=idm,DC=mydomain,DC=com

Password = MyPassWord

Bind type = Simple bind

**Here is what I've tried in PowerSHell**

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

 
##############################################################################################
# Username, Password of an admin account for the AD LDS and the location of the AD LDS
$credUsername = 'CN=canvas_service,OU=Users,OU=Infrastructure Support,DC=idm,DC=mydomain,DC=com'
$credPassword = 'MyPassWord'
$server = 'idm.mydomain.com:636'
$userName = '*'
##############################################################################################
 
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList `
        @($credUsername,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $credPassword -AsPlainText -Force))

$user = Get-ADUser -Filter {cn -eq $userName} -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=Infrastructure Support,DC=idm,DC=mydomain,DC=com" -server $server -Credential $cred
```

**Result**
Get-ADUser : Unable to contact the server.

I can't find any PowerShell examples on the web that include credentials and SSL that can point me in the corect direction.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The AD Module uses ADWS as far as I know, if you want to use LDAPS you likely need to use `adsi`

Answer (score 0):

As in my comments, the [Active Directory Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/?view=windowsserver2022-ps) uses [Active Directory Web Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/services-hub/health/remediation-steps-ad/configure-the-active-directory-web-services-adws-to-start-automatically-on-all-servers) as protocol, it's not possible to use **LDAP over SSL** (LDAPS for short) with this Module. You would need to resort to [`adsi`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/adsi-objects-of-ldap) for binding and [`adsisearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) for querying.

Haven't done this in a while so it's likely that the code below won't work but hopefully can help you get on track.

```sh
$server = "idm.mydomain.com"
$port = 636
$ou = "OU=Users,OU=Infrastructure Support,DC=idm,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
$toSearch = "canvas_service"

# Below might require you to add `None` or `0` to the constructor for SimpleBind
# Beginning with .NET Framework 2.0, the default value is `Secure` or `1`.
$adsi = [adsi]::new("LDAP://${server}:${port}", "myUser", "myPasswordAsPlainText!!")
$searcher = [adsisearcher]::new($adsi)
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(@("samAccountName", "cn", "distinguishedName"))
$searcher.SearchRoot = $ou
$searcher.SearchScope = "SubTree"
$searcher.Filter = "(&(cn=$toSearch)(objectClass=user))"
$searcher.FindOne()
```